# uninitialized constant AppGenerator::Config Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, railsinstaller

I actually upgraded from Ubuntu 13.10 to Ubuntu 16.04

My rails was working fine in the previous versions. I am removing rvm and reinstalling from scratch. Yet I get this error always when I try to invoke the server

```
uninitialized constant AppGenerator::Config
Did you mean?  RbConfig
```

Do I have to define the rails path?

Comment: can you tell us your version of ruby and rails you are installing.

Comment: Its rails 5.0. After the update it's showing my rails 2

Comment: you need to update your version of rails check the stable version of rails and then do `gem install rails --version=your_version_number`

Answer (score 0):

Somehow (I think after installing Redmine) my enviroment collapsed.

By following steps I removed and reinstalled Rails. Now the error had gone:

1. `gem uninstall rails`
2. `gem uninstall railties`
3. `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -`
4. `sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`
5. `gem install rails -v 5.1.0` (Use your own rails version!)
6. At your project root `bundle install`

Cheers,