# having trouble with creating new rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've previously created a rails app with the simple "rails new fileName", but for some reason, I'm getting the following error when I attempt to create a new app:

```
$ rails new powTr
uninitialized constant AppGenerator::Config
Did you mean?  RbConfig
```

I'm not sure what this means/where to look.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: what is your rails version?

Comment: There are steps in this similar question, it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39738700/uninitialized-constant-appgeneratorconfig-error

Comment: It might be worth installing Rails again to be sure you're getting the latest version.